# Apache FOP - Not Accepting Custom Font

Tags: apache, fonts, apache-fop

While trying to use `Apache FOP` to use custom fonts (Google Lato Font), I am getting below error. I have converted `ttf font` to `xml` as per documentation & kept both ttf & xml files in same directory `resource`

> WARNING: `Font "Lato,normal,700" not found`. Substituting with "any,normal,700"
>   WARNING: `Font "Lato,normal,400" not found`. Substituting with "any,normal,400".

Configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fop version="1.0">
    <base>.</base>
    <source-resolution>72</source-resolution>
    <target-resolution>72</target-resolution>
    <default-page-settings height="11.00in" width="8.50in"/>
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <filterList>
                <!-- provides compression using zlib flate (default is on) -->
                <value>flate</value>
            </filterList>
            <fonts>
                <font metrics-url="Lato-Regular.xml" kerning="yes" embed-url="Lato-Regular.ttf">
                    <font-triplet name="Lato" style="normal" weight="400"/>
                </font>
                <font metrics-url="Lato-Bold.xml" kerning="yes" embed-url="Lato-Bold.ttf">
                    <font-triplet name="Lato" style="normal" weight="700"/>
                </font>
            </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```

Execution code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, TransformerException, URISyntaxException {
        File fopConf = new File("\\fop.xconf");
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(fopConf);

        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/Hello.pdf")));

        try {
            // Step 3: Construct fop with desired output format
            Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);

            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources/foo.xsl").toURI()));
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

            // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
            Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

            Source src = new StreamSource(new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources/name.xml").toURI()));
            // Step 6: Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing

            transformer.transform(src, res);

        } finally {
            //Clean-up
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

*Any suggestions? I have wasted entire day looking on Google, but unable to find a relevant solution. I have seen stackoverflow posts mentioning about using realtive/absolute path, sub-fonts, etc. but none of them seems to work*

- `FOP 2.2`
- `Would use this code on web for dynamic pdf generation`
- `JDK 1.8`

Comment: Did you try to run a standalone FOP using your sample config file? BTW, font metrics files are not needed anymore from FOP version 2.0 (or so). You can cut this attribute ``metrics-url`` for sure. The best way to find out problems - try to figure out if this is FOP itself issue or embedded code issue.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on using standalone FOP? I would be using the execution code mentioned in the question on web for dynamic pdf printing for one or more files. 

Yes, while reading the documentation, I found that conversion of fonts to xml has been deprecated but I still can't seem to figure out why it keeps on throwing warning and surprisingly there are no errors.

Note: I have just started using FOP...

Comment: Thanks your suggestion worked. Using standalone it worked and I noticed that while running through command line I got the same warnings when I hadn't specified the configuration file. After specifying conf file location it worked smoothly.

My execution code had the same issue and it was never reading the file so default configuration were loaded. I have now corrected the execution code in the description

Answer (score 2):

Followed @Eduard approach & executed code using Standalone FOP (Command Line) & figured out that my execution code was not reading `conf` file.

- Changed the execution code to read it as a file, instead & it worked. Above execution code is edited & works fine.
- XML conversion is not required in FOP 2.2